# class-validator validate nested object based on parent properties NestJs

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I want to get value of **type** property in class B for validate class A.

Class A is used as a property type for the property `a` in Class B.

```js
class Content1 {}

class Content2 {}

class A {
  @IsValidContent()
  content: Content1 | Content2;
}

class B {
  @Type(() => A)
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  a: A;

  type: string;
}

export function IsValidContent(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return (object: Object, propertyName: string) => {
    registerDecorator({
      name: "isValidContent",
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      constraints: [],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {

          const type = args.object["type"]; // how to get type properties from parent
          switch (type) {
            case "X":
              return isValidType(value, Content1);
            case "Y":
              return isValidType(value, Content2);
            default:
              return false;
          }
        },
      },
    });
  }
}
```

How to get **type** properties from class B in order to validate the property `content` in class A?

Validation decorator is `IsValidContent`

Comment: Is your current implementation not working?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Yes, the args variable only contains properties of the child class. I cant get type property of the parent class

Comment: My current solution is to validate in the parent class, and then retrieve the value of the parent class to call the value of the child class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same problem.

I have created a validator that add parent object in each child:

```js
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';
import {
  Validate,
  ValidationArguments,
  ValidationOptions,
  ValidatorConstraint,
  ValidatorConstraintInterface,
} from 'class-validator';

@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'customValidator', async: false })
export class AddParentRefConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  defaultMessage(): string {
    return '';
  }

  validate(
    obj: object,
    validationArguments: ValidationArguments,
  ): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    // add the parent ref on obj
    const parentRef = new WeakRef(validationArguments.object);
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'parentRef', {
      get: function () {
        return parentRef;
      },
    });
    Exclude()(obj, 'parentRef');
    return true;
  }
}

export function AddParentRef(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return function (target: object, propertyKey: string | symbol) {
    return Validate(AddParentRefConstraint, validationOptions)(
      target,
      propertyKey,
    );
  };
}
```

A parentRef member is added in each object where the annotation is needed. Next, you can use it. I have using the @Exclude of class-transfomer on the property to ensure that the field if removed from serialisation, but if you you custom serialization, you should take care of it.

Next you can do this:

```js
class Content1 {}

class Content2 {}

class A {
  @IsValidContent()
  content: Content1 | Content2;
}

class B {
  @AddParentRef()
  @Type(() => A)
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  a: A;

  type: string;
}

export function IsValidContent(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return (object: Object, propertyName: string) => {
    registerDecorator({
      name: "isValidContent",
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      constraints: [],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {

          const type = args.object.parentRef["type"];
          switch (type) {
            case "X":
              return isValidType(value, Content1);
            case "Y":
              return isValidType(value, Content2);
            default:
              return false;
          }
        },
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, i think u can improve this feature on class-validator github

Answer (score -1):

You can use the getParentObject method provided by ValidationArguments to get the parent object of the current property being validated.
You can then access the type property of class B to use it in the IsValidContent decorator.
here is the updated IsValidContent decorator:

```js
export function IsValidContent(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return (object: Object, propertyName: string) => {
    registerDecorator({
      name: "isValidContent",
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      constraints: [],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
          const parentObject = args.getParentObject();
          const type = parentObject["type"];
          switch (type) {
            case "X":
              return isValidType(value, Content1);
            case "Y":
              return isValidType(value, Content2);
            default:
              return false;
          }
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Property 'getParentObject' does not exist on type 'ValidationArguments'

Comment: try this: 
`const parentObject = args.object as B;`
`const type = parentObject.type;`

Comment: args.object not included any class B properties