# Class validator send parent property to nested objects

Tags: validation, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm having issues writing some nested validation in NestJS using class-validator and class-transformer packages.

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { GradeValidator } from '../validation';
import { IsIn, Validate, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';


export class CurrentGradeDto {
  @Validate(GradeValidator)
  grade: string;
}

export class OnboardDto {
  @IsIn(['system1', 'system2', 'system3', 'system4'])
  gradingSystem: string;

  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => CurrentGradeDto)
  currentGrades: CurrentGradeDto[];
}
```

I'm sending multiple grades inside the nested object `currentGrades` and I need to validate each one against the property stored inside `gradingSystem` of the parent class.

Is there any way to send `gradingSystem` information to the `GradeValidator` class?

Comment: i have find another topic resemble to this one. maybe it can be a reference.
[class-validator validate nested object based on parent properties NestJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185106/class-validator-validate-nested-object-based-on-parent-properties-nestjs/76581012#76581012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is close to what @HaiAlison proposed. The @Validation decorator must be present inside the parent class:

```
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { GradeValidator } from '../validation';
import { IsIn, Validate, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';


export class CurrentGradeDto {
  grade: string;
}

export class OnboardDto {
  @IsIn(['system1', 'system2', 'system3', 'system4'])
  gradingSystem: string;

  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => CurrentGradeDto)
  @Validate(GradeValidator) <---- Here
  currentGrades: CurrentGradeDto[];
}
```

Then the **first parameter** inside the validate method of GradeValidator is an array of grades and the **second parameter** (args) contains the grading system information:

```
export class CurrentGradeValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface 
{
  validate(grades: CurrentGradeDto[], args: ValidationArguments) {
    const { gradingSystem } = args.object as OnboardDto;
    for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
      const grade = grades[i].grade;
      if () {
       //check if current grade is in gradingSystem
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Now if the validation fails it will trigger the defaultMessage method. The idea is now to iterate once again over the array to display all of the grades that failed the validation:

```
defaultMessage(args?: ValidationArguments): string {
    let errMessages: string[] = [];
    const { gradingSystem, currentGrades } = args.object as OnboardDto;

    for (let i = 0; i < currentGrades.length; i++) {
      const grade = currentGrades[i].grade as any;
      if (!GradeUtil.gradeIsInSystem({ grade, gradingSystem })) {
        errMessages.push(grade);
      }
    }

    return `Invalid current grades ${errMessages.join(
      ',',
    )} for the specified grading system ${gradingSystem}`;
  }
```

#### Bonus tip

Another cool trick that I found out is that you can define a private property inside the constructor of the class which will contain the error message depending on what condition failed:

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'gradeValidator', async: false })
export class GradeValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(private errMessage: string) {}

  validate(payload: any, args: ValidationArguments) {

    if (check 1) {
      this.errMessage = `error message 1`;
      return false;
    }

    if (check 2) {
      this.errMessage = `error message 2`;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  defaultMessage(args?: ValidationArguments): string {
    return this.errMessage;
  }
}
```

Using this approach you don't need to have a predefined error message.

Answer (score 0):

In my case check increases validation, I will put @Validation in the parent class
and my class to check like this below (edited the same question variables):

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'checkGradeValidator', async: false })
export class GradeValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(nestedObject: CurrentGradeDto, args: ValidationArguments) {
    const parent = args.object as OnboardDto; // this is parent object
    // Your logic here
    return true; //if return false => throw error
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return `your message validates`;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that approach but the downside is that you can't return a specific message on which grade failed the check inside the defaultMessage method.

Comment: yes, but you can findIndex the field name to know where the position is like this below:

`return 'invoice_details.${args.value.findIndex(
      (t) => !t.hasOwnProperty('stockroom_id'),
    )}.stockroom_id should not be empty';`

Comment: But what if multiple grades fail from the nested object? How to compose the error message then? You can do it but you're stepping out of the class-validator convention where when each property fails it has its own error message inside the message array. Thanks for the answer!